# Detecting div size with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to detect a divs height and use the value to resize a column so it stretches the entire height of the page.

I have been able to do this by grabbing the window height with:

```
var $pheight = $(window).height();
```

but that only works on pages where the content doesn't go beyond the fold.

i have one page where the content spans beyou the fold and am finding that the original script doesn't help for that page. Original script:

```
var $pheight = $(window).height();
$('#col_left').css('height', $pheight);
});
```

I am thinking I need a conditional like this:

```
var $pheight = $(window).height();
var $contentdiv = $('#content');
var $contentheight = $contentdiv.height();

    if($contentheight > $pheight){
        $('#col_left').css('height', $contentheight);   
    }else{
        $('#col_left').css('height', $pheight);     
    }
```

Problem is when I test with an alert:

```
alert($contentheight);
```

I get undefined as a value...

Finally the question

How do I detect the #content height?
The #content just scales with the content within so no css to define the height.

Thanks all for any help with this

Comment: You can use an alternate solution: set the css property 'min-height' to the document's height, then let it grow naturally when the child div requires it.

Note that this only works if your child div is not using 'position:absolute'.

Answer (score 1):

I think `$(document).height()` is what you're looking for:

```
var $pheight = $(document).height();
    $('#col_left').css('height', $pheight);
});
```